# android value passing from fragment to fragment using recyclerview not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app i want to pass value from one fragment to another fragment. Here i am using Recyclerview Adapter. My code is shown below.

FriendsFragment.java

```
public class FriendsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://192.168.43.7/work/ecom/2/1.php";
String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "image_title";
String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";
String JSON_IMAGE_ID = "id";

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
RequestQueue requestQueue ;
public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);






    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    Log.d("LOGTAG", "Response :"+response);

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}


public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageId(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_ID));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, getContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

static String categoryId;
Context context;
List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;
ImageLoader imageLoader1;

private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();
public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){
    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {
    GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);
    Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());
    imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                    Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
            )
    );

    Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
    public TextView imageid;
    public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;
    public CardView cardView ;
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;
        networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview1);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
                MessagesFragment fragobj=new MessagesFragment();
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

            }
        });
    }
}

private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter = new GetDataAdapter();
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;
    }
}
}
```

GetAdapter.java

```
public class GetDataAdapter {

public String ImageServerUrl;
public String ImageTitleName;
public String ImageId;

public String getImageServerUrl() {
    return ImageServerUrl;
}

public void setImageServerUrl(String imageServerUrl) {
    this.ImageServerUrl = imageServerUrl;
}

public String getImageTitleName() {
    return ImageTitleName;
}

public void setImageTitleNamee(String Imagetitlename) {
    this.ImageTitleName = Imagetitlename;
}

public String getImageId() {
    return ImageId;
}

public void setImageId(String ImageId) {
    this.ImageId = ImageId;
}

}
```

SampleHolder.java

```
public class SampleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public SampleHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
}
}

 when i using
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
                //set Fragmentclass Arguments
                MessagesFragment fragobj=new MessagesFragment();
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

it is not passing value to message fragment or not going to message fragment.

How it possible plese help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your Adapter class:

```
//in On click
MessagesFragment fragobj=new MessagesFragment();
 Bundle bundle=new Bundle()
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
fragobj.setArguments(mBundle);
switchFragment(R.id.container, fragobj); //replace container ID


public void switchFragment(int id, Fragment fragment) {
    if (context == null)
        return;

    //MainActivity is your activity where FriendsFragment is called
    if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
        mainActivity.loadFragment(id, fragment);
    }
}
```

now in your activity write this code:

```
 public void loadFragment(int id, Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(id, fragment, fragment.toString());
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `FragmentTransaction` and then `commit()` the transaction to go to any fragment

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
//set Fragmentclass Arguments
MessagesFragment fragobj=new MessagesFragment();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
context.getSupportFragmentManager()//context should be an Activity cotext
    .beginTransaction() 
    .replace(R.id.container, fragObj)//R.id.container is id of container where the current fragment is added
    .commit();
```

Comment: I have place the code RecyclerViewAdapter.java. Then it shows error cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: as I have added in the comment, you should have activity context to do that

Comment: How it possible in activity context.

Comment: try this `((AppCompatActivity)v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()` where `v` is View object from `onClick(View v)` method

Comment: It shows the same error 'cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager'